# DoubleRenderError in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

```
before_action :set_blacklisted_nfts, only: %i[blacklisted_nfts]
def blacklisted_nfts
   if  @blacklisted_nft.present?
    redirect_to destroy and return
   end
end
def destroy
  success = false
  message = 'Unable to delete NFT!'
  if !current_user.admin?
     message = 'This action require admin privileges!'
  elsif @nft.destroy
     success = true
     message = 'NFT deleted successfully!'
  end
  render layout: false, locals: {
  type: success ? 'success' : 'error',
  message: message,
  nft_id: @nft.id
  }
end
private

def set_blacklisted_nfts
@blacklisted_nft = BlacklistedNft.create(contract_address: @nft.contract_address,   contract_type: @nft.contract_type, token_id: @nft.token_id, chain: @nft.chain)
end
```

can anyone guide me where is an issue am having this error:

```
Error: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that
you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

Comment: can you share the backtrace from the log?

Comment: On which controller action does this happen? How does the request look like?

Comment: this all code i have in nets_controller an am trying to handle delete and blacklisted_nfts in this this controller

Comment: `redirect_to destroy` you're calling `destroy` that renders something and then trying to redirect. you can't do both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `redirect_to destroy` that's actually calling the `destroy` method.  You might be trying to redirect to the destroy method, but it's calling it directly.

You can't actually redirect to anything other than another "GET" action, the redirect just responds back to the browser with a URI and the browser just calls a GET on it, you can't have a POST or DELETE or any other http method (aka: http verb).

Probably instead in that condition, you just want to do a `@blacklisted_nft.destroy` and then `redirect_to :back, notice: "Deleted @blacklisted_nft.name"` or something.